# Colorize specific strings in a text

Tags: shell, grep, command

I would like to highlight a few strings while outputting a text file. For example the **literals** `[2]`, `quick` and `lazy` in:

```
... => any number of lines with non-matching content
He’s quick but lazy.
...
• The future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams [2].
...
I’m lazy but quick (2 times faster); is there a difference when "lazy" comes before "quick"?
...
```

My intuitive approach would be to use `grep` for the colorization (in fact I'm not fixed on any specific tool):

```bash
grep -F -e '[2]' -e 'quick' -e 'lazy' --color file.txt
```

But it has two problems:

1. It filters out the lines that don't match while I want to include them in the output.
2. It doesn't highlight all the matching strings; it seems like the order in which the `-e` expressions are provided matters (problem noticed with macOS `grep`).

My expected output (with `<...>` standing for the colorization) would be:

```
... => any number of lines with non-matching content
He’s <quick> but <lazy>.
...
• The future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams <[2]>.
...
I’m <lazy> but <quick> (2 times faster); is there a difference when "<lazy>" comes before "<quick>"?
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -n -F -e '[2]' -e 'quick' -e 'lazy' --color=always file.txt |
awk -F':' '
    FILENAME==ARGV[1] { n=substr($1,9,length($1)-22); sub(/[^:]+:/,""); a[n]=$0; next }
    { print (FNR in a ? a[FNR] : $0) }
' - file.txt
```

would use `grep` to find and highlight the strings, and then `awk` would print the `grep` output for those lines and the original lines from the input file otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

###### UPDATE

I found a way using `grep -E` instead of `grep -F`. As a side-effect, matching a **literal** string will require its **ERE-escaping**.

The method is to build a single regex composed of the union of the search strings plus an additional `$` anchor (for selecting the "non-matching" lines).

Hence, for highlighting the literals `[2]`, `quick` and `lazy` in the sample text, you can use:

```bash
grep -E '\[2]|quick|lazy|$' --color file.txt
```

---

**edit:** I replaced the `^` anchor with the `$` one because on **macOS**:

- `grep -E '\[2]|quick|lazy|^' --color` doesn't highlight any word
- `grep -E -e '\[2]|quick|lazy' -e '^' --color` **SEGFAULTS !!!**